# SQL Eliminate Duplicates and largest date in set

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a request to provide a list of unique email addresses to our marketing group.  I can produce the list without issue.  They now want to add the latest date where that email address was used.  The information for the email addresses is in a table called customer and the transaction date is in a table called activity.  The two tables are joined by an account number field.
If I write the code
 `select c.email, a.transactiondate
   from customer c join activity a on
   c.account = a.account
   where a.transactiondate between '12/1/2016' and '12/31/2016'`
I end up with multiple transaction dates for the emails.  It isn't many but the marketing people do not want to deal with it.

Adding distinct to the select does reduce the number but only by the combination of the email and transaction date.  I think what I really need is the distinct emails and then the top date for that account number.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by email and use aggregate functions to get the most recent date.

```
select c.email, max(a.transactiondate)
from customer c join activity a on
c.account = a.account
where a.transactiondate between '12/1/2016' and '12/31/2016'
group by c.email
```